# An OpenSSL Signing Application

Tags: python

I am new to Python.

Currently developing an application, whose purpose is to accept a directory path from user and create a file(sha_generated_file.txt)
with SHA256 of each file name inside the passed directory subfolders except those mentioned in ignored list.

Sample entry in sha_generated_file.txt is
`SHA256(out_configuration/PRC/afile.bin)= 3c62546a67921acbd4e85c70af794270c095177213781e7d6d1000762d849100`

Once the sha_generated_file.txt is generated it will be sent for signing(by invoking another tool, that is not in the scope).

The resultant of signing is a Sample.p7s file, which is parsed using `ASN1PARSE` and other `OpenSSL` commands to get some
certificates out of p7s file.

Finally the certificates will be copied to some designated location.

You may not be able to execute the entire program , but individual functions can be executed with minimal modifications ( Sorry I could not possibly come up with version that be run by you, becuase it has dependency of openssl, third party tool etc)

**Process goes like this:**

The ideal folder structure of of input path is

```
 --configuration
       |__PRC
       |
       |__QRC
       |
       |__RRC
       |
       |__XRC
```

Out of this, i want SHA256 of all the files(only file names, not the contents) from all directories except XRC.

**Note**: There is a condition for ordering of files in the resultant sha_generated_file.txt

All the files in required directories should be sorted alphabetically (following ascii values)
( This part of code can be found in `create_sha_signer_dir`,`create_sha_file`,`make_file_list`,`make_sha_format`,`fetch_sub_directory_contents` etc. )

But before proceeding for SHA calculation, I need to setup some most frequently used directories for temporary processing purpose during the run time of my application.
( This particular code can be found in `setup_tool_envdirs`)

I have also handled the cases where only parent directory is passed as input or till the required directory is passed (code can be found in `check_path_is_valid_config`)

There are other set of functions implemented for miscellanios purpose likes extracting bytes from certain offsets and converting different file types(crl to pem etc)

The application has to run in `Python2.7` and `Python3`, It currently works with 2.7 and also mostly it works with `Python3` (few errors for byte string  conversions etc. )

I am looking for optimizing the code in all possible ways ( optimization/reduce number of lines/correct usage/stanadard/speed/memory/ etc. )

**code**

```
import os
import sys
import hashlib
import string
from ctypes import windll
from os.path import dirname, abspath
from shutil import copyfile
import logging

ignored = {"XRC"}

#constants to replaced 
OUT_CONFIGURATION = 'out_configuration'
CONTAINS_CONFIG = 'contains_config'
PARENT_HAS_CONFIG = 'parent_has_config'
SHA256_FILE_NAME = 'sha_generated_file.txt'
P7S_FILE_NAME = 'Sample.p7s'
OPENSSL_EXE_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Installs\\openssl.exe'
OFFSETS_LENGTH_FILE = 'crl_offset_n_lengths.txt'

config_dir_path = ''
parent_of_config_dir = ''
signature_file_path = ''
sha_file_path = ''
g_crl_dir_path = ''

# tells whether the input path has(only till parent is passed ) or contains(full path passed)
config_dir_path_flag = ''

def copy_pem_files_to_config_crl():

    global g_crl_dir_path
    global sha_file_path
    
    crl_dir = sha_file_path
    config_crl = g_crl_dir_path
    filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(crl_dir) if f.endswith(".pem") ]
    print ( "number of files in crl dir are: {}".format(len(filelist) ))
    if len(filelist) > 0:
        for f in filelist:
            copyfile(os.path.join(crl_dir, f),ref_config_crl+"\\"+f)
        return True
    else:
        return False

def convert_crl_to_pem():
    #openssl crl -inform DER -in crl3.crl -outform PEM -out crl3_pem.pem
    crl_dir = sha_file_path
    filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(crl_dir) if f.endswith(".crl") ]
    logging.info ( "number of files in crl dir are: {}".format(len(filelist)))

    if len(filelist) > 0:
        for f in filelist:
            crl_file = os.path.join(crl_dir, f)
            logging.info ( "crl_file = %s", crl_file )
            fnamepos = crl_file.find(".crl")
            pem_file = crl_file[:fnamepos]
            pem_file = pem_file+".pem"
            logging.info ( "pem_file = %s", pem_file )
            CRL_TO_PEM_CMD = OPENSSL_EXE_PATH + " crl -inform DER -in " + crl_file + " -outform PEM -out " + pem_file
            #logging.info ( f"CRL_TO_PEM_CMD ={CRL_TO_PEM_CMD}" )
            logging.info ( "CRL_TO_PEM_CMD = %s" + CRL_TO_PEM_CMD )
            os.system(CRL_TO_PEM_CMD)
        return True
    else:
        logging.error("There are not CRL files present in %s ",crl_dir)
        return False

#sample lines for below 3 functions
#2286:depth=4 hl=4 l=5321 cons: next
def get_length(line):
    return int (line.split(':')[1].split(']')[0])

def get_offset(line):
    return int (line.split(':')[0].split('[')[1])

def extract_crl(offset,length):
    crl_file = '';

    #checking this just to avoid creating files with length 4 and below
    if length > 4:
        crl_file = sha_file_path + "crl_" + str(offset) + ".crl"
        logging.info ( "%s created" ,crl_file)
        with open(crl_file, 'wb') as fw , open(signature_file_path+P7S_FILE_NAME, 'rb') as fr:
            try:
                logging.info ( "file open success" )
                fr.seek(offset)
                crl_content = fr.read(length)
                logging.info ( "length of crl_content = %d", len(crl_content))
                fw.write(crl_content);
                fw.close()
                fr.close()
            except IOError:
                logging.error ( "file open failed %s",crl_file )
    return

def create_crls():
    olaf = sha_file_path+OFFSETS_LENGTH_FILE

    if os.path.exists(olaf):
        with open(olaf, 'r') as f:
            try:
                logging.info ( "file open success" )
                line = f.readline()
                while len(line.strip()) != 0 :
                    offset = get_offset(line)
                    length = get_length(line)
                    extract_crl(offset,length)
                    line = f.readline()
                f.close();
            except IOError:
                logging.error ( "file open failed %s",olaf )
    else:
        logging.error ( "file does not exist %s",olaf )

#get offset and length file
'''
sample contents parse_txt are

2282:depth=3 hl=4 l=12096 cons: start_indi
2286:depth=4 hl=4 l=5321 cons: next
2290:depth=5 hl=4 l=4785 cons: next

extract as long as this condition satifies

next_offset = prev_offset + prev_length 

'''
def create_offset_and_length_file(parse_txt):
    o_l_f = sha_file_path+OFFSETS_LENGTH_FILE
    with open(o_l_f, 'w') as fw:
        try:
            logging.info ( "file open success" )
        except IOError:
            logging.error ( "file open failed" )

        fo = open(parse_txt);
        line = fo.readline()
        while len(line.strip()) != 0 :
            if "cont [ 1 ]" in line:
                line = fo.readline()
                offset = line.split(':')[0]
                length = line.split('=')[3].split()[0]
                length_i = int (length) + 4
                offset_i = int (offset)
                output = "["+ offset + ":" + str (length_i) + "]"+"\n"
                fw.write(output);
                line = fo.readline()
                while len(line.strip()) != 0 :
                    if " " + str(offset_i + length_i) + ':' in line:
                        offset = line.split(':')[0]
                        length = line.split('=')[3].split()[0]
                        length_i = int (length) + 4
                        offset_i = int (offset)
                        output = "["+ offset + ":" + str (length_i) + "]"+"\n"
                        fw.write(output);
                    
                    if str(offset_i + length_i) + ':' in line:
                        offset = line.split(':')[0]
                        length = line.split('=')[3].split()[0]
                        length_i = int (length) + 4
                        offset_i = int (offset)
                        output = "["+ offset + ":" + str (length_i) + "]"+"\n"
                        fw.write(output);

                    line = fo.readline()
            line = fo.readline()
    fw.close()

def create_parse_txt(p7sdest_path):
    global sha_file_path
    cmd = OPENSSL_EXE_PATH
    cmd = cmd + " asn1parse -inform DER -in " + p7sdest_path + " >> " + sha_file_path + "parse.txt"
    logging.info ( "parse command is %s", cmd )
    result = os.system(cmd)
    logging.info ( "create_parse_txt result = %d", result )
    return result

def copy_signed_p7s():
    global sha_file_path
    global parent_of_config_dir
    global config_dir_path
    global signature_file_path
    
    p7s_file_src = sha_file_path + "Sample.p7s"
    p7s_file_dest = signature_file_path

    logging.info ( "p7s_file_src= %s", p7s_file_src )
    logging.info ( "p7s_file_dest=%s", p7s_file_dest )
    
    if os.path.exists(p7s_file_src) == True and os.path.exists(p7s_file_dest) == True: 
        logging.info ( "both path exists" )
        #copyfile should have full path including filename as destination and its blocking so no need to collect return value
        if os.path.isfile(p7s_file_src) == True:
            copyfile(p7s_file_src, p7s_file_dest+"Sample.p7s")
            return True
        else:# This should not be reached
            logging.error ( "not file" )
    else:
        logging.error ( " one of the paths does not exist" )
    return False

def create_signingP7S_file():
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
    logging.info ( "os.getcwd()=%s", curr_dir )
    BAT_PATH = "C:\\XXX\\YYY\\Tool\\Test\\"
    batdir = os.chdir(BAT_PATH)
    logging.info ( "os.getcwd2()= %s", os.getcwd())
    TOOL_SCN_PATH = "scenes\\sign_temp.config"
    ret = os.system("tool_test.bat"+' -prop_file='+TOOL_SCN_PATH)

    if ret == 0:
        logging.info ( "Creation of P7S Success" )
        if True == copy_signed_p7s():
            logging.info ( "p7s copy success" )
            return True
        else:
            logging.error ( "p7s copy failed" )
    else:
        logging.error ( "Creation of P7S Failed" )

    os.chdir(curr_dir)
    print ( os.getcwd() )

def write_sha_entry_to_file(sha_entry):
    global sha_file_path
    sha_file = open(sha_file_path+SHA256_FILE_NAME, "ab")
    logging.info (" sha_entry = {}".format(sha_entry))
    sha_file.write(str(sha_entry))
    sha_file.close()

def calc_hash256(filename):
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        bytes = f.read() # read entire file as bytes
        readable_hash = hashlib.sha256(bytes).hexdigest();
        return (readable_hash)

def make_sha_format(file):
    '''
    make the filename format as require by sha file
    '''
    config_pos = file.find('\\'+OUT_CONFIGURATION)+1
    config_path_sha = file[config_pos:]
    config_path_sha = config_path_sha.replace("\\","/")
    shakey = calc_hash256(file)
    shakey_fmt = "SHA256("+config_path_sha+")= "+str(shakey)+'\n'
    write_sha_entry_to_file(shakey_fmt)
    return shakey_fmt

def fetch_sub_directory_contents(sPath):
    for sChild in sorted(os.listdir(sPath)):
        if sChild not in ignored:
            sChildPath = os.path.join(sPath,sChild)
            if os.path.isdir(sChildPath):
                fetch_sub_directory_contents(sChildPath)
            else:
                sChildPath = make_sha_format(sChildPath)
        else:
            logging.info ( "%s present in ignored list", sChild )

def make_file_list(cwd_rc):
    '''
        makes the sorted file list from out_configuration directory
    '''
    logging.info ( cwd_rc )
    sorted_list = []
    listOfFiles = sorted(os.listdir(cwd_rc))
    logging.info ( listOfFiles )
    for entry in listOfFiles:
        if entry not in ignored:
            sorted_list.append(cwd_rc+'\\'+entry)
        else:
            logging.info ( "%s present in ignored list",entry)
    logging.info ( "sorted_list" )
    logging.info ( sorted_list )
    for entry in sorted_list:
        if os.path.isfile(entry):
            entry = make_sha_format(entry)
        elif os.path.isdir(entry):
            fetch_sub_directory_contents(entry)
    return True

def create_sha_file(config_dir):
    return make_file_list(config_dir)

def get_drives():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
            drives.append(letter)
        bitmask >>= 1

    return drives

def create_sha_signer_dir():

    '''
    Function to create the directory for SHA256 file of input path
    Scans the window system for existing drives and takes the first drive it finds and creates a "temp" folder there
    If "temp" is not present it will be created, else checks whether sha256 file is present, if present deletes it and creates new one.
    :return the SHA256 path excluding the file name 
    '''

    drives = []
    drives = get_drives()
    sha_signer_path = drives[0]+':\\temp\\'
    if not os.path.exists(sha_signer_path):
        print ( " creating ", sha_signer_path )
        os.makedirs(sha_signer_path)
    else:
        print ( sha_signer_path + " already exists, deletes sha file if present" )
        isExist = os.path.exists(sha_signer_path+SHA256_FILE_NAME)
        if isExist == True:
            os.remove(sha_signer_path+SHA256_FILE_NAME)
    return sha_signer_path

def startSign():
    global config_dir_path
    global sha_file_path
    global signature_file_path
    global parent_of_config_dir

    logging.info ("config_dir_path = %s", config_dir_path)
    logging.info ("parent_of_config_dir =%s", parent_of_config_dir)

    temp_sha_file_path = create_sha_signer_dir()

    sha_file_path = temp_sha_file_path
    logging.info ( "sha_file_path = %s", sha_file_path )

    result = create_sha_file(config_dir_path)
    if True == result:
        logging.info ( "SHA creation success" )
        result = create_signingP7S_file()
        if result == True:
            logging.info ( "p7s creation success" )
            result = create_parse_txt(signature_file_path+P7S_FILE_NAME)
            if result == 0:
                logging.info ( "parse success" )
                create_offset_and_length_file(sha_file_path + "parse.txt")
                create_crls()
                if convert_crl_to_pem() == True:
                    copy_pem_files_to_config_crl()
                    result = True
                else:
                    result = False
            else:
                logging.error ( "parse failed" )
                result = False
        else:
            logging.error ( "p7s creation failed" )
            result = False
    else:
        logging.error ( "SHA creation failed" )
        result = False

    return result

def remove_existing_crl_files(crl_dir):
    filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(crl_dir) if f.endswith(".pem") ]
    logging.info ( "number of files in crl dir are: {}".format(len(filelist)))
    if len(filelist) > 0:
        for f in filelist:
            os.remove(os.path.join(crl_dir, f))
        return True
    else:
        return False

def create_crl_path(crl_path):

    if not os.path.exists(crl_path):
        logging.info ( " creating %s", crl_path)
        os.makedirs(crl_path)
    else:
        logging.info ( crl_path + " already exists, deletes crl files if present" )
        result = remove_existing_crl_files(crl_path)
        if result == True:
            logging.info ( "existing crls deleted")
        else:
            logging.info ( "crl dir is empty")
    return crl_path

def create_signature_dir(sign_path):

    if not os.path.exists(sign_path):
        print ( " creating ", sign_path )
        os.makedirs(sign_path)
    else:
        print ( sign_path + " already exists, deletes p7s file if present" )
        isExist = os.path.exists(sign_path+P7S_FILE_NAME)
        if isExist == True:
            os.remove(sign_path+P7S_FILE_NAME)
    return sign_path

def check_path_has_configuration(ipath):
    if ipath.endswith("\\"):
        config_path = ipath + OUT_CONFIGURATION
    else:
        config_path = ipath + '\\'+OUT_CONFIGURATION
    if os.path.exists(config_path) == True and os.path.isdir(config_path) == True:
        return config_path
    else:# This should not hit in any case
        print (" **parent does not have out_configuration dir** ")
        return ''

def get_config_dir(ipath):
    global config_dir_path_flag
    logging.info ("config_dir_path_flag =%s", config_dir_path_flag)
    
    if config_dir_path_flag == CONTAINS_CONFIG:
        return ipath
    elif config_dir_path_flag == PARENT_HAS_CONFIG:
        config_path = check_path_has_configuration(ipath)
        if config_path:
            return config_path
        else:
            return ''

def get_parent_of_config_dir(config_dir):
    return dirname(abspath(config_dir))

#input path will be checked for whether it contains out_configuration directory or its parent, in that case returns True
#if none then returns False
def check_path_is_valid_config(ipath):
    global config_dir_path_flag
    result = ipath.endswith('\\'+OUT_CONFIGURATION) == True or ipath.endswith('\\'+OUT_CONFIGURATION+'\\') == True
    if(result == True):
        logging.info ("input path contains out_configuration : ")
        config_dir_path_flag = CONTAINS_CONFIG
        logging.info ("config_dir_path_flag = %s", config_dir_path_flag)
        return result
    else:
        logging.info ("input path looks like parent of out_configuration, checking for out_configuration")
        if ipath.endswith("\\"):
            config_path = ipath + OUT_CONFIGURATION
        else:
            config_path = ipath + '\\'+OUT_CONFIGURATION
        logging.info (" the created config_path = %s", config_path)
        if os.path.exists(config_path) == True and os.path.isdir(config_path) == True:
            logging.info ("parent has out_configuration ")
            config_dir_path_flag = PARENT_HAS_CONFIG
            logging.info ("config_dir_path_flag = %s", config_dir_path_flag)
            return True
        else:
            logging.warning ("out_configuration dir not present for signing")
            return False

def setup_tool_envdirs(rc_path):
    global config_dir_path
    global parent_of_config_dir
    global signature_file_path
    global g_crl_dir_path

    # check for validity of input path
    if  True == check_path_is_valid_config(rc_path):
        config_dir_path = get_config_dir(rc_path)
        if config_dir_path:
            parent_of_config_dir = get_parent_of_config_dir(config_dir_path)
            signature_file_path = config_dir_path + "\\signature\\"

            sign_file_path = create_signature_dir(signature_file_path)
            crl_files_path = create_crl_path(signature_file_path+"crl");
            g_crl_dir_path = crl_files_path
            logging.info ( "crl_files_path = %s", crl_files_path )

            logging.info ("config_dir_path = %s", config_dir_path)
            logging.info ("parent_of_config_dir = %s", parent_of_config_dir)
            logging.info ("signature_file_path = %s", signature_file_path)
            logging.info ("sign_file_path = %s", sign_file_path)
            
            return True
        else:#This part should not be hit
            logging.error ("Looks like some corruption in configuration")
            return False
    else:
        logging.error ( "configuration is not present in input path: %s" + ipath )
        return False

def parse_cmdline_params():
    nargs = len(sys.argv)
    logging.info ( "Number of CMD Args:{}".format(nargs) )
    if nargs <= 1:
        logging.warning ("please pass desired path while running Tool - example: < tool.py path of desired location >")
        return False
    else:
        return True

#tool main entry function
def main_entry():
    result = parse_cmdline_params()
    if True == result:
        input_path = sys.argv[1]
        logging.info ("The input path is : %s", input_path)
        
        #First setup the freqently used directory paths
        if setup_tool_envdirs(input_path) == True:
            logging.info  ("setup is successful ")
            if startSign() == True:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            logging.info ("setup is unsuccessful ")
            return False
    else:
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(filename='debug_tool.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
    if True == main_entry():
        print ("**Successful**")
    else:
        logging.error ("**UnSuccessful**")
```

Comment: _The application has to run in Python2.7_ - why?

Comment: Currently that is what the requirement, I know it is out dated and will not be supported in future, that is the reason i want it to support pyhton3 so that we have future support.

Comment: It's not in the future. It's now. Python 2 is no longer supported. https://python3statement.org/

Comment: @Reinderien, yeah , I have already read that Python2.7 support is stopping from next year January, I have already informed my people about this. Can you please help me in improving it. I am able to make it work some how, I know it can be improved a lot. I can google it and do, but I want it to be reviewed from larger professional audience and take suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

### Python versions

As we discussed in the comments, Python 2 is no longer supported. It's time to move on.

### Hard-coded configuration

These:

```
SHA256_FILE_NAME = 'sha_generated_file.txt'
P7S_FILE_NAME = 'Sample.p7s'
OPENSSL_EXE_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Installs\\openssl.exe'
OFFSETS_LENGTH_FILE = 'crl_offset_n_lengths.txt'
```

should not be hard-coded. They should be accepted as command-line arguments, environmental variables or configuration entries. The first, second and fourth can take those values as defaults, but the third cannot have a default - that path needs to be parametric.

### Globals

Try to stop using them. Pass data around as member variables on a class, or function arguments. Only constants should generally stay global.

### Pathlib

Consider replacing `os.listdir` and `endswith` with `pathlib` equivalents. Also, for the determination of `filelist`, consider using `pathlib` to verify that the entries are all normal files.

Note that pathlib is only available in Python 3.4+.

### Logic inversion

Do the easy thing first: consider rearranging

```
if len(filelist) > 0:
    for f in filelist:
        crl_file = os.path.join(crl_dir, f)
        logging.info ( "crl_file = %s", crl_file )
        fnamepos = crl_file.find(".crl")
        pem_file = crl_file[:fnamepos]
        pem_file = pem_file+".pem"
        logging.info ( "pem_file = %s", pem_file )
        CRL_TO_PEM_CMD = OPENSSL_EXE_PATH + " crl -inform DER -in " + crl_file + " -outform PEM -out " + pem_file
        #logging.info ( f"CRL_TO_PEM_CMD ={CRL_TO_PEM_CMD}" )
        logging.info ( "CRL_TO_PEM_CMD = %s" + CRL_TO_PEM_CMD )
        os.system(CRL_TO_PEM_CMD)
    return True
else:
    logging.error("There are not CRL files present in %s ",crl_dir)
    return False
```

to

```
    if len(filelist) < 1:
        logging.error("There are not CRL files present in %s ",crl_dir)
        return False

    for f in filelist:
        crl_file = os.path.join(crl_dir, f)
        logging.info ( "crl_file = %s", crl_file )
        fnamepos = crl_file.find(".crl")
        pem_file = crl_file[:fnamepos]
        pem_file = pem_file+".pem"
        logging.info ( "pem_file = %s", pem_file )
        CRL_TO_PEM_CMD = OPENSSL_EXE_PATH + " crl -inform DER -in " + crl_file + " -outform PEM -out " + pem_file
        #logging.info ( f"CRL_TO_PEM_CMD ={CRL_TO_PEM_CMD}" )
        logging.info ( "CRL_TO_PEM_CMD = %s" + CRL_TO_PEM_CMD )
        os.system(CRL_TO_PEM_CMD)

    return True
```

### Make some unit tests

It's good that you made note of example data here:

```
#2286:depth=4 hl=4 l=5321 cons: next
```

This would be a great sample input for a unit test.

That said, your example above does not match what you're attempting to parse:

```
return int (line.split(':')[1].split(']')[0])
```

since you're looking for a bracket that does not exist in your sample input data.

### We're not in C anymore

Drop your semicolon here:

```
crl_file = '';
```

### Fail early, fail noisily

Why does this:

```
#checking this just to avoid creating files with length 4 and below
```

fail silently on insufficient length? Shouldn't you throw an exception, or at least log a warning?

### Explicit closure

Delete these lines:

```
            fw.close()
            fr.close()
```

Those files are closed when the context managers are exited.

### Redundant return

Delete this:

```
return
```

### Formatting instead of concatenation

Replace

```
            output = "["+ offset + ":" + str (length_i) + "]"+"\n"
```

with a `format` call.

### subprocess rather than os

Replace your calls to `os.system` with calls to `subprocess`.

### Redundant initialization

Delete the first line here:

```
drives = []
drives = get_drives()
```

### Temporary directories

Hard-coding to only support Window drives, and attempting to make a stand-alone temporary directory in `create_sha_signer_dir`, are both bad ideas. Use `tempfile` instead and just let it use the default system-assigned temporary directory.

### Exceptions-to-booleans

Resist the urge to sabotage the exception system, as in `startSign`. Do not convert exceptions to booleans. From `convert_crl_to_pem`, raise exceptions; and catch them where it makes sense.

### Boolean comparisons

Do not do this:

```
if True == main_entry():
```

instead, just

```
if main_entry():
```

Comment: Thanks Reinderien for the comments & suggestions. I am going to come up the modified code as per your comments, and regarding using `subprocess` instead of `system` I tried , but got some problems, but anyway  will go around it and fix now.

Comment: Great. Please be sure to post your modified code in a new question, not this one.

Comment: _the third cannot have a default - that path needs to be parametric_, how can we make that as parametric, do I have to find out installed path at runtime and use it ? And i forgot to mention i need to make an EXE (using pyinstaller) out of this program and run